# Create mysite for all users sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, my-site

I have synced 5000 users from the AD, and I wish to create a MySite for all users without them having to access the site for it to be created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

> A powershell script that will create a profile for every AD user, then
>   creates there My Site

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal")

$dom = "LDAP://CN=Users;DC=training;DC=corp"
$root = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $dom

$selector = new-object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$selector.SearchRoot = $root

$adobj = $selector.findall() | where {$_.properties.objectcategory -match "CN=Person"}
$spsite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://sharepoint2007:100")
$context = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($spsite)
$pmanager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)

ForEach ($person in $adobj)
{
$prop = $person.properties
$prop.cn

$exists = $pmanager.UserExists($prop.cn)

if ($exists -eq $false)
{
$pmanager.CreateUserProfile($prop.cn)
}

$up = $pmanager.GetUserProfile($prop.cn)
$up.CreatePersonalSite()


}
```

http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2009/02/11/Powershell-script-to-create-Active-Directory-user-Profiles-and-MySites.aspx

**EDIT**

this works for 2013 , i know its for 2010 but it works for 2013!

```
foreach($profile in $AllProfiles) 
{ 
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value     
    Try 
    { 
        if($profile.PersonalSite -eq $Null) 
        { 
            write-host "Creating personel site for  $AccountName"  
            $profile.CreatePersonalSite()        
            write-host "Personal Site Admin has assigned"  
        } 
        else 
        { 
            Write-Warning "$AccountName already has personel site" 
        } 
    } 
    Catch 
    { 
        Write-Error "Failed to create personal site for '$AccountName'" 
    } 
}
```

> Each user's personal MySite will be automatically  created when the
>   user himself click the button "My Site"/"My Profile" first time, this
>   will make user wait several seconds/minutes until the his MySite site
>   creation is finished, it can save some time (or better experience) for
>   users with using PowerShell to provision the users' MySites
>   previously.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Pre-Provision-SharePoint-ec781ee9

Comment: Since this post is from 2009 I guess it applies to SharePoint 2007 (or 2010). Did you try this out in 2013?

Comment: please check my edit out! its for 2010 but works and tested in 2013! the first script i know is for 2007/2010 but it also works for 2013 but needs ammending!

Comment: As I do this but for users that are Office365

Comment: Does that work if users access directly SP MySite ? Without going on a SP Site first, and then Click on "One Drive" or "MySite" ? What if user directly goes on my.sharepoint.contoso.com (which is the MySite collection)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the script which I downloaded from [Pre-Provision SharePoint 2010 MySite (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Pre-Provision-SharePoint-ec781ee9) on a SharePoint Server 2013 production environment. After slight modifications, this script creates MySites for all users.

But to avoid filling the database with MySites that shouldn't be there, I added an if-statement (now commented out) to enable a more in control process. Use this script (in test first) and add working MySites to your selected users.

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://MySiteHostURL"
$context = Get-SPServiceContext -Site $site
$upm =  New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$AllProfiles = $upm.GetEnumerator()

foreach($profile in $AllProfiles)
{
    $AccountName = $profile[[Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PropertyConstants]::AccountName].Value

    #if ($AccountName -eq "DOMAIN\User")
    #{
        Try
        {
            if($profile.PersonalSite -eq $Null)
            {
                write-host "Creating personel site for  $AccountName" 
                $profile.CreatePersonalSite()       
                write-host "Personal Site Admin has assigned" 
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Warning "$AccountName already has personel site"
            }
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error "Failed to create personal site for '$AccountName'"
        }
    #}
} 
$Site.Dispose();
```